# Isolating href contents using xpath in python

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping

I'm looking for the text within the href of the "next" page button on kijji located at the bottom of the page.

Link: https://www.kijiji.ca/b-apartments-condos/edmonton/c37l1700203

href is this one:

```
href="/b-apartments-condos/edmonton/page-2/c37l1700203"
```

Main issue is that within the "pagination class" there are multiple href's and are not always in the same order (its not always the 10th href).

This is what I have so far:

```
response.xpath("//*[@class='pagination']/a[10]/@href").extract_first()
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It needs to be xpath? Can the solution be using BeautifulSoup?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Using this as part of a Scrapy project. Ideally it would be xpath but if speed won't be compromised then I'm open to BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 1):

If you need hyper-reference value of Next byutton, you can use below XPath:

```
//a[@title="Next"]/@href
```

You can use it as below:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

response = requests.get("https://www.kijiji.ca/b-apartments-condos/edmonton/c37l1700203").content
source = html.fromstring(response)
url = source.xpath('//a[@title="Next"]/@href')[0]
```

Comment: @Anderson I tried but it doesn't seem to work:   
relative_next_url = response.xpath("//a[@title='Next']/@href").extract()

Comment: Hmm... I tried with requests+lxml.html and got required output `['/b-apartments-condos/edmonton/page-2/c37l1700203']`

Comment: how would you go about modifying the following to make it work:

relative_next_url = response.xpath('//a[@title="Next"]/@href')[0].extract()

Comment: This seem to be scrapy issue. I don't know how to fix XPath as it's already working fine...

Comment: Working in scrapy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using CSS selectors built-in within BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.kijiji.ca/b-apartments-condos/edmonton/c37l1700203'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

print(soup.select_one('.pagination a[title^=Next]')['href'])
```

Prints:

```
/b-apartments-condos/edmonton/page-2/c37l1700203
```

This will select `<a>` tag with attribute `title` that begins with `Next`. This `<a>` tag needs to be under tag with class `.pagination`.

Answer (score 0):

You need this for Scrapy:

```
next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@title="Next"]/@href').extract_first()
if next_page_url:
    next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
    yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.your_callback)
```